# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: {saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I was following a Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API Tutorial, i followed the steps as indicated and was able to train and successfully exported a plain saved model, i named in SSDFINAL

first i defined the paths and files that are needed like below:

```
    LABEL_FILENAME = 'label_map.pbtxt'
    PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'],LABEL_FILENAME)
    print(PATH_TO_LABELS)

    IMAGE_PATHS = os.path.join(paths['TEST_IMAGE_PATH'],'test1.jpg')
    print(IMAGE_PATHS)

    PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(paths['MODEL_PATH'],'SSDFINAL')
    print(PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR)
```

```
    paths = {
        'TEST_IMAGE_PATH': os.path.join('content','drive','MyDrive'),
        'MODEL_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow','workspace','training_demo','exported-models'),
        'ANNOTATION_PATH': os.path.join('Tensorflow','workspace','training_demo','annotations')
    
    }

    files = {
        'LABELMAP': os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], LABEL_MAP_NAME)
    }
```

the results were good

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zb0s.png)

but when i'm trying to load the model using the given code

```
    import time
    from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
    from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

    PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL = PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR + "/saved_model"

    print('Loading model...', end='')
    start_time = time.time()

   # Load saved model and build the detection function
    detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL)


    end_time = time.time()

    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

    print('Done! Took {} seconds'.format(elapsed_time))
```

i received an error

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3OUC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xVzy.png)

it says there were no saved_model.pb in the path,
but there is a saved_model.pb on my drive

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX2MY.png)